# IF formula is getting error in Google Sheets Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I tried `IF` formula in Google Sheets script like

```
=IF(D:D=False, "PAID", "NOT PAID")
```

but it's showing error.

Any other substitute formula for this condition?

Comment: `D:D` isn't a cell. Attempting to compare a range to a boolean seems silly.

Comment: No, it is not silly. This notation just uses the corresponding (from the same row as the cell with the formula) cell from `D:D` in it. https://i.imgur.com/pMowlh2.png Thus you can have the same formula in all the cells along `D:D` and not `D1` in the 1st row, `D2` in the 2nd and so on. Sometimes it is useful.

Comment: Hey, OP. What does "FORMULA IN GOOGLE SHEETS SCRIPT" means? What error do you get?

Comment: i am trying to script for google sheet, as i want formula in column "K" for fillDOwnRange, and the formula is =IF(D:D=False, "Paid", "Not paid"), this formula works in google sheet, but its not working in script mode

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is an array formula, which has nothing to do with Google Apps Script.

```
=ArrayFormula(if(D2:D=false,"Paid","Not Paid"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, and i want to use this formula in Google Sheet Script

Comment: @Mathankumar please include your script code and a description of the error you are getting. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)